# Im making a c# winform login and signup application. i just want to check the username availablity in my app

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

```
    private void signupBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usertxt.Text == "Username" || passtxt.Text == "Password" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(usertxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passtxt.Text))
        {
            DialogResult DR_defaultError = MessageBox.Show("Validation Erorr !\n\n1) *Fill all Fields.\n\n2) *Cannot have default Username and Password.", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            if (DR_defaultError == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                this.Close();
                th = new Thread(againOpenSignup);
                th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                th.Start();
            }
            else if (DR_defaultError == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // creating a reading stream (for checking the pre-created username)
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"AllUserData//" + usertxt.Text + ".txt");
                string username = reader.ReadLine();

                if (usertxt.Text.Equals(username))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This Username is Taken !", "Erorr !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"AllUserData//" + usertxt.Text + ".txt");
                writer.WriteLine(usertxt.Text);
                writer.WriteLine(passtxt.Text);

                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();

                DialogResult DR_backToLogin = MessageBox.Show("New username and password created.\n\nNow you can Login.\n\nGo back to Login?", "SignUpDone!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                if (DR_backToLogin == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    this.Close();
                    th = new Thread(redirectLoginForm);
                    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    th.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm searching usernames availability inside the file named same as username for example: if the username is "danish" then the file name is same as "danish".

The problem is when if there is username like for example "Danish" and "danish". My code is recognizing both as same username. but they are different. I tried several things but couldn't help myself.

Comment: ". I tried several things but couldn't help myself."  What have _you_ tried? why _your_ solution failed to accomplish _your_ desired result

Comment: Is this app running on Windows? Windows file and directory names are not case-sensitive. Danish.txt and danish.txt both refer to the same file on a Windows system.

Comment: If you need to distinguish 'danish' from 'Danish' then obviously you cannot use a case-insensitive file system as user database. Also, think what happens to the poor users 'C:/X' and 'COM1'. You might get around this by using a Base64-encoding of the user name as file name.

Comment: Windows 10, provide a way to use case sensitive files.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/

Comment: I've removed the C#4 tag because if you need your code to build for C#3 then that's your lowest common denominator.

Comment: This seems to be a trivial username and password prompt ; why are you using multiple threads and COM?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is going to work, but here goes:

[Based on GetFileSystemEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfilesystementries?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var path = @"AllUserData//";
var filter = "*.txt";
string[] txtEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path, filter); 
var fileExists = txtEntries.ToList().Where(te => te.Equals(usertxt.Text)).Any();
```

I am assuming that you have a unix or a windows 10 case sensitive folder for storing the files.

Comment: You should really post the relevant info from your comment above here. How to set the case sensitivity for folder's files in windows.

Comment: the app is running on windows 10.